# Find a child tag after getting an array of all parent tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list and in each item is

```
<span>
    <span>
        <img />
        <a />
        <b />
    </span>
</span>
```

There is other data inside the nodes, but I can't post that.
My problem is that I need to get some attributes is the first `<span>` and the `<a>` tag.

I can get the first span successfully with

```
$NeighborhoodSpans = $(sNeighborhoodHTML).find('span');
```

`$(sNeighborhoodHTML)` is the html list

then, I iterate like this:

```
$NeighborhoodSpans.each(function ()
{
}
```

I can't get the 'a' tags. I've tried

```
$neighborhoodAnchorTag = $(this).html().filter('a');
$Hi = $(this).html();
$neighborhoodAnchorTag = $Hi.find('a');
```

But jquery says that .find and .filter aren't supported functions of the object.

Can someone please help me with getting attributes in both the first `<span>` tag an attribute in the `<a>` tag which is in the `<span>` tag?

Comment: Have you tried giving your span tags unique identifiers via _id=_ or _data-_? And then using $("span#UniqueID").children();

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the `.html()`.  If `this` is the top of a branch, then you can change this: `$(this).html().filter('a');` to this: `$(this).find('a');`  For further help, please describe what your starting point in the hierarchy is.  What is the value of `this` when you start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have something like

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span>
            <span>
               <img />
               <a />  // this text will print
               <b />
           </span>
         </span>
         <span>
            <span>
               <img />
               <a />
               <b />
           </span>
         </span>
    </li>
     <li>
         <span>
            <span>
               <img />
               <a />  //and this text will print
               <b />
           </span>
         </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

loop throught li

```
$('li').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('> span:first > span > a').text());
});
```